# Viewing duplicate named global variables in the debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 files with the following simple code.

Linkertest.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Foobar.h"

char x = 5;
char y = 5;

int main()
{
    ChangeX();
    x = 'a';
    return 0;
}
```

and Foobar.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int x;

void ChangeX()
{
    x = -1;
}
```

Foobar.h

```
#pragma once

extern void ChangeX();
```

When stepping this code in the Visual Studio 2015 debugger, the debugger windows choose to display the value of **int x**; (Ignoring **char x**). (I understand this is not a good thing to do). Having a look at the disassembly (and map file) I can see that the linker correctly gave int x and char x separate memory allocations, and writes to them correctly. Does anyone know a way to get the debugger to display the value of char x ?

Thanks

Comment: It should show the correct x depending on the scope you are currently inside. If it does not you should report a bug to microsoft. That is if someone can duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Can you please post _all_ the code.

Comment: That's what's happens when you *hide* variables using the same name for different variables in different scopes. However, using the VS2015 (and later, and earlier) I think you could just switch files, then using the cursor (pointer) you could select the variable from`Linkertest.cpp` and add a watch of it. Then it should reference the correct variable.

Comment: This is all of the code, except for the Foobar.h file which contains only an extern for the ChangeX function.

Comment: @MEHM, I edit my answer, if possible, you could add your comment and vote the feedback I submitted for you, of course, use the VS2017 would be a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it using VS2015 and VS2017.

The VS2015 really has this issue:

[image]

But it works well in VS2017 now:

[image]

So for this issue, if possible, I suggest you use the VS2017 version.

Of course, if you just have to use the VS2015, you could also report this feedback here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx

Comment: Thanks, we will be switching to VS 2017 soon. Good to hear that issue is fixed!